# IIS hosted wcf service returns blank when I browse through the service operation but its able to browse to the base address with the .svc extension.

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

My IIS is able to browse until "http://localhost:50706/LoginService.svc" but returns blank when I try to call the wcf operation "http://localhost:50706/LoginService.svc/login?email=maiyanemokoena@gmail.com&password=123" which is suppose to return the data of the user with the particular email.

When I run the wcf service on visual studio it works perfectly.

My login interface is below:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILoginService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "login?email{email}&password={password}", ResponseFormat =
            WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        BaseUser Login(string email, string password);
    }
```

Here is my web.config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
     <!--Stuff that Thato added in order to expose more endpoints-->
    <services>

     <service name="WCF.LoginService" >
       <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding"
        contract="WCF.ILoginService"></endpoint>
       <host>
         <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:50706/LoginService.svc/"/>
         </baseAddresses>
       </host>
       <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"> </endpoint>
    </service>

    <!--The end of what Thato added-->  
    <behaviors>   

        <endpointBehaviors>   
        <behavior name="webHttpBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>

      <behavior name="basicHttpBehaviour">
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>


      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
         </behavior>

        <behavior name="WCF_Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Could you please explain, why I get a blank page on IIS when I try to acces the wcf operation that is accessed by providing the uri template parameter

Comment: Try to change `UriTemplate = "login?email{email}&password={password}"` to `UriTemplate = "login?email={email}&password={password}"`

Comment: i think u missed "=" before {email} the uriTemplate should be       `UriTemplate = "login?email={email}&password={password}"`

Comment: Thanks but still no changes